# Richfaces 4 bug in datatable with datascroller validation when empty

Tags: validation, jsf, datatable, richfaces

I have a screen in my Richfaces application which uses a datatable and datascroller, with validation to ensure that data is filled.
( example to simulate the problem, full example can be found [here](https://github.com/kdemetter/richfaces-bug/blob/master/src/main/webapp/index.xhtml)

```html
<h:form id="articleForm" >

   <h:panelGroup layout="block">
    <rich:messages globalOnly="true" />
    <rich:dataTable value="#{productModifyBean.articles}" var="article" id="articleTable"
     rows="15"  >
     <rich:column headerClass="headerOverflow artNrColumn">
      <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="articleNumber" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{article.articleNumber}"/>
     </rich:column>
     <rich:column headerClass="headerOverflow shortNameColumn">
      <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="Name" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{article.shortName}" />
     </rich:column>
     <rich:column headerClass="headerOverflow quantityColumn" >
      <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="Quantity" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:inputText value="#{article.quantity}" required="true"
       requiredMessage="This is required" converterMessage="Error conversion"
       id="modifyArticleFormatQuantity" >
      </h:inputText>
      <rich:message for="modifyArticleFormatQuantity" errorClass="errorColorRed" />
     </rich:column>

    </rich:dataTable>
    <rich:dataScroller for="articleTable" renderIfSinglePage="false" boundaryControls="show" fastControls="hide" execute="@form" render="articleTable"
     stepControls="show" style="float:right;" />
   </h:panelGroup>

   <br style="clear: both" />
   <br style="clear: both" />
   <div align="right" style="clear: both">
    <a4j:commandButton value="#{msgs['button.modify'] }" styleClass="submitButton"
     render="#{facesContext.validationFailed ? '@none' : 'articleForm'}"
     actionListener="#{productModifyBean.modifyProduct}">
    </a4j:commandButton>

   </div>

  </h:form>
```

Data validation should happen when the user presses the submit button ( to save the data) , and when the user using the pagination to go to a different page.

When clicking the submit button after leaving one field empty, the behaviour is normal : it shows an empty field with the remark 'this is required'

[image]

However, when instead moving to a different page ( for example clicking on the '2' page button ) , validation happens correctly, but the old value is put back into the screen, thus stating that the value should be filled but showing it filled in with a value.

[image]

Anyone have any idea what the reason for this problem could be, and how to resolve it ? Is this a bug in RichFaces, or am I overlooking something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by trial and error :

If I change the datascroller to use render="@region" , the screen is correctly rendered.

```
 <rich:dataScroller for="articleTable" renderIfSinglePage="false" boundaryControls="show" fastControls="hide" execute="@form" render="articleTable"
                    stepControls="show" style="float:right;" />
```